# Turn Object of Nested Objects into an Object of Array Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I hope the title and this description aren't too confusing.

**WHAT I HAVE:** An object containing two parent-objects (`firstGroup` and `secondGroup`).  Each contains the children-objects.

```js
const dataObject = {
  firstGroup: {
    0: {
      title: '0-firstGroup',
      description: '0th item in firstGroup!',
      added: 2018,
    },
    1: {
      title: '1-firstGroup',
      description: '1st item in firstGroup!',
      added: 2019,
    },
    2: {
      title: '2-firstGroup',
      description: '2nd item in firstGroup!',
      added: 2020,
    },
  },
  secondGrounp: {
    0: {
      title: '0-secondGroup',
      description: '0th item in secondGroup!',
      delicate: true,
      timestamp: '10:30:25',
    },
    1: {
      title: '1-secondGroup',
      description: '1st item in secondGroup!',
      delicate: true,
      timestamp: '14:03:11',
    },
  },
};
```

**DESIRED RESULTS:** I'd like the returned object's properties to be parent-arrays, containing the respective children-objects as elements.

```js
resultsDesired: {
  firstGroup: [
    {
      title: '0-firstGroup',
      description: '0th item in firstGroup!',
      added: 2018,
    },{
      title: '1-firstGroup',
      description: '1st item in firstGroup!',
      added: 2019,
    },{
      title: '2-firstGroup',
      description: '2nd item in firstGroup!',
      added: 2020,
    },
  ],
  secondGrounp: [
    {
      title: '0-secondGroup',
      description: '0th item in secondGroup!',
      delicate: true,
      timestamp: '10:30:25',
    }, {
      title: '1-secondGroup',
      description: '1st item in secondGroup!',
      delicate: true,
      timestamp: '14:03:11',
    },
  ],
};
```

**BONUS RESULTS:** If you'd be willing to try this out as well, I'd also be interested in the returned object's properties to be parent-objects, containing label's of the parent identifiers and group-arrays with the children-objects as elements.

```js
resultsBonus: {
  firstGroup: {
    label: 'firstGroup',
    group: [
      {
        title: '0-firstGroup',
        description: '0th item in firstGroup!',
        added: 2018,
      }, {
        title: '1-firstGroup',
        description: '1st item in firstGroup!',
        added: 2019,
      }, {
        title: '2-firstGroup',
        description: '2nd item in firstGroup!',
        added: 2020,
      },
    ],
  },
  secondGrounp: {
    label: 'secondGroup',
    group: [
      {
        title: '0-secondGroup',
        description: '0th item in secondGroup!',
        delicate: true,
        timestamp: '10:30:25',
      }, {
        title: '1-secondGroup',
        description: '1st item in secondGroup!',
        delicate: true,
        timestamp: '14:03:11',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**EDIT - MY PREVIOUS ATTEMPT:** @RyanWilson made a good point, I should have shown that I actually attempted this. Made lots of attempts, all of which were terrible. Below is the last one before asking...

```js
const arr = [];

Object.keys(dataObject).forEach((key) => {
  arr.push(dataObject[key]);
});

console.log('arr ', arr);
/* LOG
[
  0: {
    0: {
      title: "0-firstGroup"
      description: "0th item in firstGroup!"
      added: 2018
    },
    1: {
      title: "1-firstGroup"
      description: "1st item in firstGroup!"
      added: 2019
    },
    2: {
      title: "2-firstGroup"
      description: "2nd item in firstGroup!"
      added: 2020
    },
  },
  1: {
    0: {
      title: "0-secondGroup",
      description: "0th item in secondGroup!",
      delicate: true,
      timestamp: "10:30:25",
    },
    1: {
      title: "1-secondGroup",
      description: "1st item in secondGroup!",
      delicate: true,
      timestamp: "14:03:11",
    },
  },  
]
*/
```

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer to your post if you make an attempt. Asking for people to write code for you is not what this site is intended for.

Comment: @RyanWilson, but based on appeared answers this site serves well "write code for me" questions ;)

Comment: @TrialAndErrors, do we get bonus votes for providing bonus results as well? ;)

Comment: @Fabio Yeah, unfortunately, not everyone follows those standards.

Comment: @RyanWilson New to this site, sorry. I tried lots of things that ended up wrong and bad, I will include the last attempt.

Comment: @TrialAndErrors Thank you for adding your attempt. Much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the nested objects to an Array.

```js
const
    dataObject = { firstGroup: { 0: { title: '0-firstGroup', description: '0th item in firstGroup!', added: 2018 }, 1: { title: '1-firstGroup', description: '1st item in firstGroup!', added: 2019 }, 2: { title: '2-firstGroup', description: '2nd item in firstGroup!', added: 2020 } },secondGrounp: { 0: { title: '0-secondGroup', description: '0th item in secondGroup!', delicate: true, timestamp: '10:30:25' }, 1: { title: '1-secondGroup', description: '1st item in secondGroup!', delicate: true, timestamp: '14:03:11' } } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(dataObject)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, Object.assign([], v)])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do with `Object#entries` to create the array with `[key,value]` pair of object and `Array#reduce` recreate the object

```js
const arr = { firstGroup: { 0: { title: '0-firstGroup', description: '0th item in firstGroup!', added: 2018, }, 1: { title: '1-firstGroup', description: '1st item in firstGroup!', added: 2019, }, 2: { title: '2-firstGroup', description: '2nd item in firstGroup!', added: 2020, }, }, secondGrounp: { 0: { title: '0-secondGroup', description: '0th item in secondGroup!', delicate: true, timestamp: '10:30:25', }, 1: { title: '1-secondGroup', description: '1st item in secondGroup!', delicate: true, timestamp: '14:03:11', }, }, };

const res = Object.entries(arr).reduce((acc,[label,group])=>( acc[label] = {label,group:Object.values(group)},acc),{});

console.log({resultsBonus:res})
```